# Events getting misfired for first child component in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a child component. It is a custom image grid scrollable component. I have used scroll dispatcher scrolled event to determine if we have reached the end of the list. I will emit a custom event to parent to notify that the user has scrolled to the end of the list. So the parent can fetch next set of data.

I have used the child component 2 times in my parent component as I needed 2 image grid lists.

The issue I am facing is if I scroll to the bottom of the second image grid list the event is getting fired for first image grid component even though both component has different functions to receive the event. I can't find a solution anywhere.

Please provide some inputs and thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide some code that we can help you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.